# how to parse array to multiple choice QNA flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, array-map

i have some data from API

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "id": "1",
    "pertanyaan": "Berapa Penghasilan Anda",
    "type": "radio_opt",
    "opsi": "[\"1 juta\",\"2 Juta\",\"3 Juta\",\"4 Juta\",\"> 4 Juta\"]",
    "urutan": "3"
}
```

how to parse this array to Map<String, bool> ?
anyone please help me :

my code :

```
Map<String, bool> values = {
    'foo': true,
    'bar': false,
  };


if(question.type == "check_opt"){
          // choices = jsonEncode(question.opsi) as List<List<String>>;
          // choices = question.opsi as List<List<String>>;
          values = question.opsi as Map<String, bool>;
        }else if (question.type == "radio_opt"){
          // values = question.opsi as Map<String, dynamic>;
          multi = jsonEncode(question.opsi);
        }
```

[to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvRY3.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which options should be true - my code below tests for the prefix `">"`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

main(List<String> args) {
  String data = '''{
    "status": 200,
    "id": "1",
    "pertanyaan": "Berapa Penghasilan Anda",
    "type": "radio_opt",
    "opsi": "[\\"1 juta\\",\\"2 Juta\\",\\"3 Juta\\",\\"4 Juta\\",\\"> 4 Juta\\"]",
    "urutan": "3"
}''';
  Map<String, dynamic> question = json.decode(data);
  if (question["type"] == "radio_opt") {
    var opts = json.decode(question["opsi"]);
    Map<String, bool> map = {for (var opt in opts) opt: opt[0] == '>'};
    print(map);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{1 juta: false, 2 Juta: false, 3 Juta: false, 4 Juta: false, > 4 Juta: true}
```